# IndexError - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexing

The following code produces a `IndexError: list index out of range` error. I have no idea why, the code seems to be correct.

```
numlist = [2, 12]

for number in numlist:
    numlist[number] *= 3

print numlist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`number` is *an element in `numlist`*, not an index. Python `for` loops are [*for each loops*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop), where each element in the iterable (`numlist`) is being assigned to thee target (`number`):

```
>>> numlist = [2, 12]
>>> for number in numlist:
...     print number
... 
2
12
```

If you wanted to alter `numlist` in place you'd need to *generate* indices, using the `enumerate()` function:

```
for index, number in enumerate(numlist):
    numlist[index] = 3 * number
```

or you could re-build the list with a list comprehension:

```
numlist = [number * 3 for number in numlist]
```

Demo:

```
>>> numlist = [2, 12]
>>> for index, number in enumerate(numlist):
...     numlist[index] = 3 * number
... 
>>> numlist
[6, 36]
>>> numlist = [2, 12]
>>> [number * 3 for number in numlist]
[6, 36]
```